# User to user trading functionality / module in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I would like to implement a functionality in Drupal that allows users to trade among themselves. So for example user 1 can ceate an ad and other users can buy it. Has anyone heard about module that can be used in order to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one of solutions: [Ad or ed_classified module] + Ubercart + [uc_node_checkout or uc_node_access]